# Bcrypt is always false after the first login

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I am using bcrypt to hash the user password. The issue is that when I compare the plain text password with the hashed password, the result is `true` only on the first login. After the first login, I get "Unable to login".

**User schema**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
     },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        // validate()
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        // validate()
    }, 
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            require: true
            }
        }]
})


// Defining my custom function "findByEmailAndPassword" so that I can use it directly on the model "User"
userSchema.statics.findByEmailAndPassword = async function(email, password){
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    if(!user){
        throw new Error("Unable to login")
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    console.log("isMatch", isMatch) // It fails here. On the first login it works, but after the first I get "Unable to login" and the result of isMatch is always false   
    if(!isMatch){ 
        throw new Error("Unable to login")
    }
    return user
}

// Hash the password with a middleware and bcrypt
userSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
    // "this" refers to the user
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password , 8)
    next()
})


const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)


module.exports = User
```

**User login router**

```
router.post("/api/users/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.send({
            user: user,
            token: token
        })
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(400).send("Unable to login")
    }
})
```

Comment: Since you have `Unable to login` on both failure paths, are you sure this is the latter that fails?

Comment: I think so because when I `console.log(isMatch)`, I get `false` expect on the first login. I am gonna try to change the error and see if it helps with debugging.

Comment: could be possible that your `pre('save')` is running more than once ? If that the case your password is being re hashed.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, that was the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want my pre('save') mongoose function to operate only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60794031/i-want-my-presave-mongoose-function-to-operate-only-once)

Comment: Yes, it does. I will accept it if you write it.